# Displaying images

Tags: blackberry

Hi I am developing a application where I need to display number of images with some conditions. The images should display one by one on the screen when next button is clicked.Here the size of all images is 360x480.When the image is display then all other fields like next and previous buttons should be added to the screen.How to paint those images.Can anybody please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

You can display images with the [BitmapField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BitmapField.html).  Use the setBitmap() method to change the image.

Edit: Ok, so you would want to do something like this, put the names of all your bitmaps in an array, have the button's listeners increment or decrement the array index and display that bitmap.  So your next button might look like this:

```
ButtonField nextButton = new ButtonField("Next");
nextButton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener(){
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
    {
        if(arrayIndex + 1 >= bitmapArray.length)
        {
            return;
        }
        arrayIndex++;
        Bitmap image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource(bitmapArray[arrayIndex])
        myBitmapField.setBitmap(image);
    }

});
```

This assumes that your images are preloaded with your app and are stored in the 'res' directory, if you're downloading them from online or they're stored on the filesystem the way you load the bitmap will be somewhat different.  I haven't compiled this code so it may have some bugs but this is roughly what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.Actually I need to set new background images when each click on next button and the fields next,previous buttons should add on the new new image.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific with what you want.  Do you want to make the image a background image on the BlackBerry Home Screen or just as the background image on your app?  When you say "add on" the new image do you mean you want to replace the existing image or have the user scroll down to see the new image.  Do you want the next and previous buttons to be displayed over the image?  Are you having problems getting the buttons to work?

Comment: Hi Jonathan when  the app is start i have a home screen which display next and previous buttons.Now everytime when I click on next or previous buttons it should replace the old home screen with new one.

Comment: you don't actually need to "change" the screen, you can just replace the `Bitmap` on the `BitmapField` using the `setBitmap` method (just remember to do this while having the *EventLock* with `invokeLater`)